# PyTorch Convolutional Accuracy frozen

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I'm having problems making my PyTorch program's accuracy go higher than 0.  The loss that I'm getting also doesn't change.

The code:

```
train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(dataset=test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)
 
class ConvNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, numclasses):
        """
        args
        """
        super(ConvNet, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(1, 64, 3, 1, 1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
        )
        self.layer2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(64, 256, 3, 1, 1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
        )
        self.layer3 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(256, 512, 3, 1, 1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
        )
        self.fc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(512*3*3, 512),
            nn.Linear(512, numclasses)
        )
 
    def forward(self, net):
        net = self.layer1(net)
        net = self.layer2(net)
        net = self.layer3(net)
        net = net.view(net.size(0), -1)
        net = self.fc(net)
        return net
model = ConvNet(100)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=.001)
 
total_step = len(train_loader)
loss_list = []
acc_list = []
num_epochs=3
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        # Run the forward pass
        outputs = model(images)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss_list.append(loss.item())
 
        # Backprop and perform Adam optimisation
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
 
        # Track the accuracy
        total = labels.size(0)
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        correct = (predicted == labels).sum().item()
        acc_list.append(correct / total)
 
        if (i + 1) % 20 == 0:
            print('Epoch [{}/{}], Step [{}/{}], Loss: {:.4f}, Accuracy: {:.2f}%'
                  .format(epoch + 1, num_epochs, i + 1, total_step, loss.item(),
                          (correct / total) * 100))
```

I'm not sure if my train_dataset is correct.  It's made up of 10000 tuples of images and labels.  The images have shapes like:

```
 tensor([[[0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000,
          0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000,
          0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000,
          0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000,
          0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.1098, 0.2667, 0.4196,
          0.1686, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000,
          0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
        ...
         [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000,
          0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.6510, 0.9725, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000,
          0.6510, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000,
          0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000]]])
```

and each label has a shape like:
tensor(78)

From what I can tell, when the model is running the images are unzipped properly along with the labels.  Do I need to change the images' format, or add a setting to the optimizer?  Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: What is your batch size?

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the learning rate to see if things improve. Also like @GoodDeeds said, too small a batch size may also not result in much learning for only 3 epochs.

If that doesn't work, then try running your dataset on one of the benchmark torchvision models just to see if it's your model that's the problem.